# Question about complex conjugation, and dotted/undotted indices in the 4d $\mathcal{N} = 1$ superconformal algebra

Tags: supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory, spinors, lorentz-symmetry, superconformality

The 4-dimensional $\mathcal{N} = 1$ superconformal algebra as presented in equations (2.2, 2.3, and 2.4) of the paper, "[Counting chiral primaries in N = 1 d = 4 superconformal algebras (arXiv:hep-th/0510060v2)](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0510060)" involves fermionic generators $Q_{\alpha}$ and $S_{\dot{\alpha}}$.

First of all, decomposing operators in terms of $SU(2)_l \times SU(2)_r \times U(1) \times U(1)_R$, we have

$Q_\alpha$ belongs to $(2,1)_{-\frac{1}{2},-1}$

$Q_{\dot{\alpha}}$ belongs to $(1,2)_{\frac{1}{2},1}$

$S_\alpha$ belongs to $(2,1)_{\frac{1}{2},-1}$

$S_{\dot{\alpha}}$ belongs to $(1,2)_{-\frac{1}{2},1}$

where the subscripts denote the $U(1)$ and $U(1)_R$ charges [a related question about what $\frac{1}{2}$ means in the context of $U(1)$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923299/what-is-the-frac12-representation-of-u1).]

Normally in supersymmetry, $Q_{\dot{\alpha}}$ is the complex conjugate of $Q_\alpha$. And complex conjugation interchanges left- and right-handed spinors.

An anticommutator that appears in the main reference paper cited above 
(i.e. [arXiv:hep-th/0510060v2](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-th/0510060))

$$\{Q_\alpha, (Q_\beta)^\dagger\} = \delta_\alpha^\beta\left(H - \frac{3}{2}J\right) - 4 {{\sigma_{(P)}^i}^\beta}_\alpha J_i$$

where $J$ is the $U(1)_R$ symmetry generator, $H$ is the Hamiltonian, and $\sigma^i_{(P)}$ are the Pauli matrices.

The way this equation is written does not make sense: shouldn't conjugation convert $\beta$ into $\dot{\beta}$, that is, a dotted index? Isn't $(Q_\alpha)^\dagger$ the same as $Q_{\dot{\alpha}}$?

Comment: I haven't seen the paper, but since there is a Hamiltonian in the equation, it follows that a frame of reference has been chosen. It then implies that the spinor indices are now viewed from the point of view of the spatial SO(3) symmetry, for which there are no dotted indices. Instead, the complex conjugate of a 3d spinor is a dual spinor (i.e. with the raised or lowered index so that you can form $\delta^\beta_\alpha$). The 4d spinors here simply restrict to 3d spinors, in other words.

Comment: So your point is that since H explicitly appears, time translation symmetry is explicitly broken and now all spinor indices are 3D spinor indices? Also, starting from the basic superconformal algebra (found for instance on the Wikipedia page), how does one get this particular form, with $H$ and $J$? I am guessing this is a specific basis choice. What bothers me is that the paper is using dotted and undotted indices just before these equations and doesn't make any reference to 3D spinors so far. Maybe this is standard in the field?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I misinterpreted the question (I didn't notice the "conformal"). What happens is that hermitian conjugate of $Q$ is not a $Q$ but an $S$,and usually people have a notation with hermitian-conjugate pairs $Q,S$ and $\bar Q,\bar S$. Here the author just uses $Q^\dagger$ instead of $S$ and dotted $Q$ for $\bar Q$.  The reason no dot appears is that you are working with representations of the $SO(4)$, not $SO(3,1)$, which are unitary, so complex conjugation gives you a dual representation (raises or lowers the index). The reason why $Q^\dagger$ is $S$ is similar to $P^\dagger=K$

Comment: I know what you're saying, but I am uncomfortable thinking about it this way particularly because it was drilled in my string theory class that $Q^\dagger$ is not the same as $S$. Moreover, $Q$ is the superpartner of $P$ whereas $S$ is the superpartner of $K$ and we don't think of $P$ and $K$ to be usually related by complex conjugation. Even in this paper, there is no explicit reference to the fact that $Q^\dagger$ is like $S$ (in fact the author uses all four operators). Surely there must be a cleaner way to think about this without assuming that $Q^\dagger$ is $S$?

Comment: As I said, in Euclidean signature the representations $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,0)$ are not exchanged by hermitian conjugation. Euclidean $SO(4)$ is compact, and therefore its representations are all secretly unitary. More precisely, for any rep, say $\psi_\alpha$ of $SO(4)$, there exists a positive definite matrix $g^{\alpha\beta}$ s.t. $\psi_\alpha^*\psi_\beta  g^{\alpha\beta}$ is a scalar. This is the same as to say that the complex conjugate representation is dual to the original, and define $(\psi^*)^\beta=\psi_\alpha^*g^{\alpha\beta}$. Usually we work in a basis where $g$ is identity matrix.

Comment: That said, $K$ and $P$ are hermitian conjugate in radial quantization, which is by far the most popular quantization to use in Euclidean signature, so yes, we normally think $P^\dagger=K$. This is because hermitian conjugation in radial quantization is equivalent, in a sense, to an inversion $I$, and $K=IPI$.

Comment: Are you saying that $Q^\dagger$ is like $S$ *in* Euclidean space, but not in Minkowski?

Comment: Conjugation depends on your Hilbert space, which depends on your quantization. To quantize, you foliate your space with constant time surfaces. In Minkowski you want to have them spacelike, so it is most natural to work with flat slices. In that case $P^\dagger=P$. In Euclidean case one often foliates by spheres, so the conjugation rule is different.

Comment: See e.g. [hep-th/9712074](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712074).

Comment: (My last comment here, to avoid cluttering): can you point me to the specific section in this paper where I can find a discussion of whether $Q^\dagger$ is indeed $S$?

Comment: See equation 3.15 and surrounding discussions

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, thank you for pointing this out. I overlooked two things: (a) the commutation/anticommutation relations in the paper are *not* for SO(4,2), and (b) the behavior of the operators under conjugation for SO(3). I learned something new - thank you for bringing this to my attention. I posted another question on the forum, but I figured it out moments later..I'm having a bad day making terrible gaffes about basic Yang Mills theory! I removed the question before finding out that you had replied to it -- I got a notification on my phone for it later! My apologies!

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, if you would consider writing a very short answer, it might help students who may stumble upon this in future. You could include a citation to Minwalla's paper. I'll mark it as answered then.